# Синхронизация изображений, загружаемых на разные веб-сервера

Tags: linux, api, flask, микросервисы

**Контекст**: Пишется сайт с API и Postgres'ом. Берется в расчет масштабируемость, когда одно веб приложение разворачивается на нескольких серверах с разными IP, а потом DNS каким-нибудь RoundRobin пересылает пользователя на один из них.

**Вопрос**: Как быть с изображениями, которые пользователи загружают на один из нескольких таких сайтов? Каким образом их синхронизировать между одинаковыми веб-серверами?

**Догадка**: Сейчас я предполагаю развернуть сервер для хранения на нем изображений и подключаться к одной из его папок по sshfs. Всеми серверами сразу. Так все будет синхронизировано, но вдруг sshfs упадет например, плюс нагрузка на сеть и необходимость в более дорогом железе для этого файлового сервера.

**Догадка №2**: Загружать изображение в Postgres. А когда сервер должен будет выдать изображение, сначала проверит есть ли оно у него в папке, если нет загрузит к себе на диск из PostgreSQL и спокойно выдаст. Минус метода очевиден: хранить изображения в рабочей бд очень очень плохо, я это понимаю

Как мне быть?

Comment: почему именно sshfs, можно и простым http транспортом пользоваться, у вас не нагрузки яндекса и гугла и не представляю как можно забить канал таким трафиком

Comment: файловое хранилище по сути статично, добавив http кешеирование не все запросы будут до вашего сервера доходить

Comment: Т.е. пользователь загружает файл на веб сервер. Дальше я его пересылаю на файловый сервер, удаляю, в БД кладу данные о том, как он называется и, возможно, на каком именно сервере это все храниться. А при запросах клиенты будут ходить уже на файловый сервер по http. Ну да, вполне себе подходит, благодарю вас)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Прямая ссылка

Загружайте в базу ссылку на картинку вместе с доменом сервера куда она была загруженна. Выдавайте на фронт полный урл. При аплоаде картинок меняйте сервер. Так как загрузка изображений это отдельный запрос - то нагрузка размажется по всем серверам. Тут будет минимизация по трафику и диску.

## Прокси

Проблема тут только в рейтинговой статье на которую большой трафик. Если такая проблема возникает, то можно немного улучшить верхний вариант. Картинки также 
загружаете на сервера по очереди. Пользователю выдаете ссылку вида `http://server.ex/upload_server/images/00001.jpg` на нгинксе делаете проксипасс с кешированием на `http://upload_server.server.ex/images/00001.jpg`.

Приложение может определять популярность картинки и выдавать ссылку через кеш или прямую.